# Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle ERROR

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nib, nsbundle

I have tried everything I have read on google, and StackOverflow but none of the suggestions seem to work. I have been stuck on this for 2 days trying to fix it but I hope you guys can help me out and suggest something I haven't tried...

this is what I have tried and hasn't seemed to work:

- restart mac
- restart Xcode
- restart simulator
- delete an app from the simulator
- the clean project then build then run
- change storyboard name (i changed it from ViewController to
  ViewController1 and as you see I still get the error
- made sure all the code with ViewController1 in it is spelled right
  and case sensitive
- made sure that storyboards are added to copy bundle in build phases
- deleted it from build phases and added it back
- made sure the storyboards weren't localized and vice versa
- made sure the project was added to the storyboard target in file
  inspector
- I tried disabling and enabling auto-layout both didn't work

**NONE of these seemed to work I still get this error below and it won't load my app on the simulator it just stops at the black loading screen**

```
**2013-08-27 12:07:15.057 Project52[647:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Deondrae/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/A350F56C-CC1C-462A-8D7C-63F2CB037EBC/Project52.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController1''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x159b012 0x12a8e7e 0x159adeb 0x408ef9 0x2cd7e7 0x2cddc8 0x2cdff8 0x2ce232 0x21d3d5 0x21d76f 0x21d905 0x226917 0x2bb5 0x1ea157 0x1ea747 0x1eb94b 0x1fccb5 0x1fdbeb 0x1ef698 0x25fddf9 0x25fdad0 0x1510bf5 0x1510962 0x1541bb6 0x1540f44 0x1540e1b 0x1eb17a 0x1ecffc 0x56ad 0x28d5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)**
```

I suspect that this error is being caused because of this code below... the code looks to load an xib but this is xcode 4.6 so we are using storyboards... what can i change the code to try make it work/load storyboards instead of the dated xib ?

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**UPDATE**: this is what i have now in my appdelegate.m (After trying suggestions) but i still get the error:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ViewController1"  bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** i still get the error ('NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'ViewController1')

- My storyboard file name is storyboard.storyboard
- I only have one view controller within that storyboard.
- the view controller within has a custom class of ViewController1

this is what I have in the appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController1;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic) UIStoryboard* storyboard;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

This is what I have in the appdelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard" bundle:nil];
    self.viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    self.navigationController  = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

**UPDATE 3:**

using @calinchitu code from the comments within the appdelegate.h and .m file seemed to have got rid of the error... however now I get a warning specifically after I close bracket on the code he provided on the .m file which says "Warning: Control reaches end of non-void function" only way to skip past it is with a breakpoint enabled but the warning still shows... how do I get rid of this?

**UPDATE 4:**

Add return YES; at the end of the code that @calin Chitu provided in the comments and it should get rid of the warning. HIS ANSWER IS CORRECT AND WORKED FINE BUT I DONT HAVE ENOUGH POINTS TO MARK THE ANSWER SO ANYONE ELSE WHO COMES ACROSS THIS ERROR USE HIS CODE / SUGGESTION IT WORKS - DONT FORGET THE return YES;

Comment: What is ViewController1, I see you importing ViewController but not ViewController1 and yet the NIB name you seem to be looking for is ViewController1

Comment: thats importing viewcontroller.h clearly says so thats not a storyboard... the storyboard which is the only one i have is named ViewController1 and is also the root view controller

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initiate your storyboard from appdelegate:

at appdelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic) UIStoryboard* storyboard;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

at appdelegate.m

```
self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourstoryboardname" bundle:nil];
self.viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
self.navigationController  = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];
[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

make sure in storyboard you have set StoryboardId as ViewController1 for your viewcontroller.

You can also skip the entire code above, by going to your project settings, summary, and set Main Storyboard with the storyboard you've created.

Comment: i tried setting the main storyboard as ViewController1 which is my only storyboard but i still get the error... now im gonna replace the entire line of code which i suspected to be causing this error in my appdelegate.m file with the one you just posted and see if it helps. UPDATE: i have just tried that but it gives me 8 errors now... do i also replace the -Bool part ? UPDATE 2: replacing the bool part doesnt help... is there something i should peraps put in the appdelagate.h file first before using your code?

Comment: don't confuse storyboard name with StorybordId, you should set the storyboard ID as "ViewController1" for the viewcontroller inside the storyboard. The storyoard name it's exactly the name of the storyboard file in your project, without the extension.

Comment: the storyboard ID is set to ViewController1, the storyboard name in the file inspector is set to MainStoryboard.storyboard and the custom class is set to ViewController1... all these seem right but i still get the error

Comment: please check out UPDATE 2 within the question as im still getting the error. UPDATE 3: using your code i seem to have got rid of that error but now i get a warning after i close bracket on the code you provided.. "Warning: Control reaches end of non-void function"

Comment: please check the question for UPDATE 3

Comment: THIS suggestion worked only that i get a warning but it works just that i dont have enough points to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: UPDATE 4: thanks for your help your answer worked and only that you missed out a return YES at the end which got rid of the warning i kept on getting after using your code

Answer (score 1):

You may got confused between using storyboard and using individual nib files. Do you have a ViewController1.xib at all? 
As you are telling about including the storyboard to the boundle I assume that ViewController1 is part of your (or one of yours) storyboard. If so then go for:

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
```

As you are in app delegate and not in a view controller use:

```
self.viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourstoryboardname"  bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
```

Comment: Now i get after replacing my line of code with yours.. i get error... *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x718a640>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ViewController1'' BUT I DO HAVE my storyboard named ViewController1 and also the identity set to ViewController1 and also ticked the part underneath which says use storyboard ID but still doesnt work...

Comment: where should i put this line of code? [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];

Comment: UPDATE: this is what i have now but i still get the error: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ViewController1"  bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

Comment: Multiline code is unreadable in comments. Please add this to your question.

Comment: A storyboard and a view controller are two different things, although both are created with IB. Does your storyboard really have the name `ViewController1`? Which I doubt. If you do have a storyboard than the view controller's nib is likely part of your storyboard.

Comment: OK i have updated the question with what i have now in my appdelegate.m file but i still get the error and my storyboard is called MainStoryboard.storyboard and the only view controller i have within that storyboard is named ViewController1 - i tried naming the storyboard to ViewController1.storyboard but it didnt help (file name)

Comment: Well, then it is ` storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" `

Comment: The problem is you need to set the storyboard id in the IB